# Adding KML Library JAK

Tags: kml, libraries, jak

How do I add a the JAK Library to my java project so I can use it?
I Dont understand how to I acctually make it useable in my Java Porject if it is on Gittub and I dont see the Jar Files.

Can Anyone please help me with a little guidance? I've checked online and 0 videos about it so All I can ask is help from you guys.

Comment: What build tool are you using in your java project: Maven, Gradle, Ant, etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding jar dependencies to a Java project depends on what build tools are used (e.g. Maven, Gradle, Ant, etc.). If you're using an IDE, the project can be created around the build artifact (pom.xml for Maven projects, build.gradle for Gradle, etc.) or explicitly add jar files to the CLASSPATH for that project.

If you have a Maven project, add this dependency to your *pom.xml* file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.micromata.jak</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaAPIforKml</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For Gradle project, add this to your *build.gradle* file:

```
dependencies {  
  compile group: 'de.micromata.jak', name: 'JavaAPIforKml', version: '2.2.1'
  //...
}
```

Alternatively, you can manually download the jars from the official dev.java.net [Maven 2 repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.micromata.jak%22%20AND%20a%3A%22JavaAPIforKml%22). Note that [JAK](https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak.html) depends on JAXB libraries so you will need them also. Review the POM for JAK for details.